# Windows 2003 IIS 6.0 w3wp PerfMon monitoring

Tags: iis-6, perfmon, iis

We have a number of web applications set up as Virtual Directories under one web site on Windows 2003/IIS 6.0 servers.  Each VirDir has a dedicated App Pool.  One of my users wanted to know if I could tell him how many users or how many connections were accessing a particular Application.  Using IISApp.vbs and the Process list in Task manager I was able to identify the PID and w3wp.exe instance.  But I'm not sure how to use that information in PerfMon to get the number of users/connections that are using that application.